# Fillable PDF to XML conversion in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, pdf-conversion, mlcp

I have loaded some PDF files into MarkLogic with MLCP, which were then converted to XML by the CPF default PDF conversion. Some of the PDFs were fillable, but none of the content that was filled out was included in the conversion. Is there a way to convert that?

Answer (score 0):

Are these PDF forms that have been filled by a user? If so, some converters don't carry through PDF form data. PDFTables may work - the API allows you to convert your PDFs to XML including any form data.

As an example in Python (any language can be used):

```
import pdftables_api

c = pdftables_api.Client('my-api-key')

c.xml('input.pdf', 'output.xml')
```

Comment: Yes, they are PDF forms that have been filled by a user. Do any of the MarkLogic PDF converters do this, or is the only option to convert before loading into MarkLogic?

Comment: I'm not familiar with MarkLogic but going from what you said in your initial question, I'm going to assume form data is not carried over.